# Why decode("utf-8") not working in serial?

Tags: python

using serial, am trying to send a number then reading it on the other side....error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\desk\Downloads\serialTestPy_processing3.py", line 8, in <module>
    serPrint = serPrint.decode("utf-8")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

sending code:

```
import serial
from time import sleep
ser7 = serial.Serial('COM7',19600)
while True:
    
    ser7.write(str.encode('80'))
    sleep(1)
```

Receiving code:

```
import serial
from time import sleep
ser8 = serial.Serial('COM8',19600)

while True:
    
    serPrint = ser8.read()
    serPrint = serPrint.decode("utf-8")
    print(serPrint)
```

Comment: Because the data it's reading is not valid UTF-8 ...?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=UnicodeDecodeError%3A+%27utf-8%27+codec+can%27t+decode+byte+0x98+in+position+0%3A+invalid+start+byte

Comment: Does it happen all of the time or intermittently? You should specify encoding on send instead of accepting the local install's default (`"80".encode("utf-8")`). Add a debug `print(serPrint)` before the decode so we can see what the payload is. But its all quite suspicious because I don't see any way your sender is sending 
 byte `0x98`.

Comment: it is intermittent.... well more likely not to work but if i use print(serPrint) before the decode i get the output:b'\x98'
b'\x98'
b'\x98'
b'\x98'

Comment: Solved: baud rate problem made x98 error happen

Answer (score 0):

friend!
I have tested this and worked for me,

Sending Part:

import serial
import time

```
ser7 = serial.Serial('COM7',19600) while True:
    ser7.write('80')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Receiving Part:

```
import serial
from time import sleep
ser8 = serial.Serial('COM8',19600)

while True:
    serPrint = ser8.read()
    serPrint = serPrint.decode('utf-8')
    print(serPrint)
```

Comment: where in here did you send the number "80" to serial port?

Comment: Ah yes, I edited :))

Comment: when i dont use str.encode but only "80", i get this error: TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: '80'

Comment: Have you tried  ser7.write(str.encode('utf-8') str is '80'

Comment: i didi try ser7.write(str.encode('utf-8') str is '80' does work either, same x98 error

Comment: Solved: baud rate problem made x98 error happen